# Django python project 1 search wiki

Tags: python, django

With this code

```py
def search(request):
    entries = util.list_entries()
    find_entries = list()

    search_box = request.POST.get("q", "").capitalize()

    if search_box in entries:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"wiki/{search_box}")
        
    for entry in entries:
        if search_box in entry:
            find_entries.append(entry)
        else:
            print(f'{find_entries}')
    if find_entries:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
          "search_result": find_entries,
          "search": search_box
    })
 else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {"no_result": f"No results for {search_box}"})
```

This all works for my list as follows:

```
CSS
Django
Git
HTML
Python
```

Except when I put CSS or HTML in search box.

Then I get `" No results for Html"` I know its because HTML is all caps. How do fix my search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your code is basically this:

```
if something_is_true then Response()
if something_else_is_true then Response()
```

So if both things are false ... you return nothing, which in python is `None`.

Update:
It looks like you're comparing DATA with Input:
`search_box = request.POST.get("q", "").capitalize()` turns the search string `HTML` into `Html`, so if your list contains `HTML` it will never match.

You should normalize this so that you're comparing the same thing:

```py
entries = [x.lower() for x in util.list_entries()]
search_box = request.POST.get("q", "")
if search_box.lower() in entries:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f"wiki/{search_box}")

...  # etc
```

Comment: I figured out i was missing a else...I am updating my original question

Comment: So your `util.list_entries()` returns `CSS` and `HTML` in caps? Not `Css` and `Html`?

Comment: Thank you that fixed it your awesome